# How to estimate the $\mu$ in the Bayesian regression model?

Tags: regression, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

For a simple linear regression model without intercept, that is
$$y_i=ax_i+\varepsilon_i$$
where $\varepsilon_i\sim_{iid} N(0, \tau^2), i=1,2,\dots, n$ and $x_i$ is a fixed covariate. Assume that $a|\tau \sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$. and $\tau$ is fixed.

By the least squares estimator of $a$, we know that the minimum of
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{a}x_i)^2$$
obtained at the estimator of $a$
$$\hat{a}=\frac{\sum_{i}x_iy_i}{\sum_i x_i^2}$$

***But I do not know how to use this estimator to estimate the $\mu$?***

Comment: What does "$\gamma$" refer to??

Comment: @whuber Sorry, this is $\tau$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\tau^2)$ is the prior distribution of $a$. Thus, you don't estimate $\mu$, it is a parameter that describes your initial belief of $a$ -- often this is set to $0$ to encourage low weights unless you have reason to believe another mean is better.

So after you see more data, you compute the posterior mean of $a$ using bayes rule. Then you can either set $a$ as the argmax of the posterior and perform linear regression (MAP estimate), or you can integrate out $\mu$ to derive a predictive *distribution* of $y$, again using bayes rule.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for setting $\mu=0,$ because it looks like *all* numbers are equally valid for the prior.  After all, for any real number $\lambda$ this model is identical to the model $$z_i = (a-\lambda)x_i + \varepsilon_i$$ where $z_i = y_i - \lambda x_i.$ If your reasoning is correct, than in the re-expressed model we would stipulate $a-\lambda=0,$ which is the same as $a=\lambda.$ How do you resolve this apparent contradiction?

Comment: I don't think this is a contradiction, if I understand you correctly. Generally you prefer to keep your parameters small in norm to avoid overfitting, which is why I would set mu to 0 unless I had reason to believe otherwise. This is actually equivalent to performing l2 weight decay.